# Express OpenId Connect app not redirecting after getting token

Tags: node.js, express, openid-connect

I am connecting to an Open Id Connect provider and this is my code.

```
const express = require('express');
const { auth } = require('express-openid-connect');
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;
const jwt_decoder = require('jwt-decode');  

app.use(
  auth({
    issuerBaseURL: '***',
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
    clientID: 'client_id',
    secret: 'long string',
    idpLogout: false,
    authRequired:true,
    authorizationParams:{
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'openid profile email',
    response_mode: "form_post",
    redirectUriPath: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
   
    }
  })
);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 //console.log(res)
  console.log(req.oidc.accessToken.access_token)
  var decoded = jwt_decoder(req.oidc.accessToken.access_token); // Decoding
  console.log(decoded);
  res.send(`hello ${decoded.Username} from ${decoded.OrgName}`);
  
});

app.get('/callback', (req, res) => {
    console.log("redirected")
    res.send("logged in");
  });

app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at http://localhost:3000'))
```

After authorising, it does not go to callback instead comes to '/'. I get the token there which I am able to decode. I have asked the auth server to call /callback but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not be redirected to `/callback` once you login, instead what will happen it will redirect you to something called `baseURL`.

[Here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/express/interactive#install-the-express-openid-connect-sdk) is explained what we are provided once we add `auth` to our express app (`/login`, `/logout` and `/callback` routes):

```
// The `auth` router attaches /login, /logout 
// and /callback routes to the baseURL
app.use(auth(config));
```

The Express OpenID Connect SDK handles those routes under the hood. If you want to play, you can add your `callback` route before adding `app.use(auth(config))`. But then your flow might be broken.